# Python bdist and distribute packages for install without PyPi

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

I'm developing a system that itself is not terribly complex: just a virtualenv with a collection of packages, each with their own dependencies.  All told (with dependencies), about 30 packages need to be installed.

The following constraints complicate the setup somewhat:

- The internet is not guaranteed to be accessible.  In fact we assume that PyPI is unavailable at the time of install.  (A non-network debian stable repository **is** available, which allows for virtualenv and company)
- Some of the packages/dependencies have C extensions which are essential to the performance of the application.
- It is desired that the C extentions be compiled in advance to avoid installation of GCC and company.

Within these constraints, what is the fastest, the easiest or even (preferably) the 'right' way to package (and then install) the python module dependencies?  Do I just grab the source for each package and bdist it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This questions is a bit old, but in any case, since [pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html) version 1.4 (2013-07-23), wheel has been supported as a binary distribution format with a richer interface and better support. For those finding this thread, consider using [wheel](http://wheel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead of egg.

Example usage (from the wheel documentation):

> To build wheels for your requirements and all their dependencies to a
>   local directory:
>
> ```
> pip install wheel
> pip wheel --wheel-dir=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
> ```
>
> And then to install those requirements just using your local directory
>   of wheels (and not from PyPI):
>
> ```
> pip install --no-index --find-links=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
> ```

Comment: It helped me to get rid of build permission error on OpenShift.

Comment: # Based on above, with mixing ./.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build
source ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}/bin/activate
if [ ! -f ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}/bin/activate ]; then
  virtualenv $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
fi
export PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE=${OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR}.pip/cache
export PIP_WHEEL_BUILD=${OPENSHIFT_TMP_DIR}.wheel/.cache
pip wheel --wheel-dir=${PIP_WHEEL_BUILD} -r ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/requirements.txt
pip install --use-wheel --no-index --find-links=${PIP_WHEEL_BUILD} -r ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/requirements.txt

Comment: @Ajeeb.K.P this seems like a decent answer to another question. You could open a question with the problem you were having and then answer your own question. It may help others with the same problem better than them having to find a solution in a comment to another question.

Answer (score 1):

The pip `--find-links` option supports local directories. Simply put all your sdist and egg distributions into the one directory and pip will find them there.

Binary distributions, I'd build as eggs (with [`setup.py bdist_egg`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#bdist-egg-create-a-python-egg-for-the-project)), for easy installation without the need to compile.

Comment: Yeah... eggs.... this is the major gap in my knowledge.  Looks like this, combined with things like `pip install --download-cache=testcache --no-install pyramid` are very close to what I need.

Comment: Link is dead. it requires to download setuptools.html

Comment: @ConstantinHong: the answer is 11 years old and waaaay outdated. I’ll try to update in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

The method I've settled on for now is [this](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#packaging-others-projects-as-eggs):

```sh
# To gather together all of the dependencies (ex: pymongo, ujson):
easy_install -zmaxd /my/packaging/directory pymongo>=2.3 ujson

# Secondarily, package my custom module
/mymodule/setup.py sdist
cp /mymodule/dist/mymodule.tar /my/packaging/directory/
```

Later, since most version of pip in the world don't support eggs, use easy_install to install as well. (Recent versions of pip do, I understand but not everyone is up to date):

```sh
easy_install -H None -f file:///installed/packaging/directory mymodule
```

The dependencies for mymodule Still seeing if this works, but it seems close to the 'right' way of doing things.

Thanks to Martijn for pointing me towards eggs.

Comment: We use [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) for deployments; it uses setuptools (easy_install) under the hood, so it installs from eggs just fine.

Comment: This raising interesting questions about buildout vs/with virtualenv, too.  I'll have to do some playing around.

(--Ahh. That's how language tags work)